# Is it possible to set a transition for a background in a div on hover with css if using gradients?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a heart-shaped button with this code:

MENU

```css
.heart {
  --c: red;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background:
   radial-gradient(at 70% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
   radial-gradient(at 30% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
   linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(-43% 0,50% 91%, 143% 0);
  transition: all .5s;
}
.heart:hover {
  --c: blue;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background:
   radial-gradient(at 70% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
   radial-gradient(at 30% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
   linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(-43% 0,50% 91%, 143% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
    <button id="widget-toggle" class="widget-toggle-open drawer-toggle widget-toggle-style-default" data-toggle-target="#widget-drawer" data-toggle-body-class="showing-widget-drawer" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".widget-toggle-close">
        <span class="widget-toggle-label">MENU</span>
        <span class="widget-toggle-icon">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

But the no matter how I try it, the transition doesn't work.  Is there a way to make this and have the color change on hover have a duration?

Old posts said this may not have been possible.  I did look around and didn't see any recent Question/Answers that said this may have changed, So I'm hopeful that maybe there's been some modernization?

Comment: what do you mean? I have hovered over the heart and its changing the color?

Comment: The color changes but not over a duration.  I want the color change to slow down over .5 seconds

Comment: so you want to use transition-delay?

Comment: No, I want the duration to not be instant. I want a slow change from red to blue.  not wait .5 seconds then instantly change, but gradually change from one color to the next over .5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The `background-image` property supports only the [discrete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties#discrete) animation type. This means that when you change a `background-image`, instead of cross-fading between the two images throughout the transition duration, the images simply get swapped halfway through the transition duration. This is a pretty silly situation in 2024, but it’s just one of those historical things that we are stuck with.

The simplest solution is to use an SVG element in your HTML. This is what SVG is good at: vector graphics. You then apply styles to that element using CSS.

```css
.heart {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  transition: 1.5s;
  fill: red;
}
.heart:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg class="heart" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 200 60 C 200 75.138 194.394 88.967 185.144 99.523 L 100 200.009 L 14.856 99.523 C 5.606 88.967 0 75.138 0 60 C 0 26.863 26.863 0 60 0 C 75.367 0 89.385 5.777 100 15.278 C 110.615 5.777 124.633 0 140 0 C 173.137 0 200 26.863 200 60 Z"/>
</svg>
```

But if you are stuck with HTML from somewhere else and therefore want to do it all in CSS, you could achieve it using two pseudo-elements and animating the `opacity` of one of them.

```css
.heart {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.heart::before, .heart::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.heart::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 200 200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M 200 60 C 200 75.138 194.394 88.967 185.144 99.523 L 100 200.009 L 14.856 99.523 C 5.606 88.967 0 75.138 0 60 C 0 26.863 26.863 0 60 0 C 75.367 0 89.385 5.777 100 15.278 C 110.615 5.777 124.633 0 140 0 C 173.137 0 200 26.863 200 60 Z' style='fill: red;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.heart::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 200 200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M 200 60 C 200 75.138 194.394 88.967 185.144 99.523 L 100 200.009 L 14.856 99.523 C 5.606 88.967 0 75.138 0 60 C 0 26.863 26.863 0 60 0 C 75.367 0 89.385 5.777 100 15.278 C 110.615 5.777 124.633 0 140 0 C 173.137 0 200 26.863 200 60 Z' style='fill: blue;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
.heart:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
    <button id="widget-toggle" class="widget-toggle-open drawer-toggle widget-toggle-style-default" data-toggle-target="#widget-drawer" data-toggle-body-class="showing-widget-drawer" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".widget-toggle-close">
        <span class="widget-toggle-label">MENU</span>
        <span class="widget-toggle-icon">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks beautiful, but I'm not sure how I could add that to my code.  The code is part of a theme menu button so i don't have a lot of flexibility to change it.  Is there a way to add it to the html I provided?

Comment: I have extended my answer, adding a second snippet to demonstrate how it could be done entirely in CSS.

Comment: Sorry but Yes we can add transition on background.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the gradients but you need a CSS property that with animate to fade out one color and bring in another.

This snippet uses opacity to do that, putting the red gradient on the before pseudo element and the blue on the after pseudo element.

```css
.heart {
  --c: red;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(-43% 0, 50% 91%, 143% 0);
  position: relative;
}

.heart::before,
.heart::after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(at 70% 31%, var(--c) 29%, #0000 30%), radial-gradient(at 30% 31%, var(--c) 29%, #0000 30%), linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.heart::before {
  --c: red;
}

.heart.hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.heart::after {
  --c: blue;
  opacity: 0;
}

.heart:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
  <button id="widget-toggle" class="widget-toggle-open drawer-toggle widget-toggle-style-default" data-toggle-target="#widget-drawer" data-toggle-body-class="showing-widget-drawer" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".widget-toggle-close">
        <span class="widget-toggle-label">MENU</span>
        <span class="widget-toggle-icon">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @property css at-rule for that, but firefox has only partial support.
https://caniuse.com/?search=@property

```css
@property --c {
    syntax: '<color>';
    initial-value: red;
    inherits: false;
}
.heart {
    width: 200px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background: 
        radial-gradient(at 70% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
        radial-gradient(at 30% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
        linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
    clip-path: polygon(-43% 0,50% 91%, 143% 0);
    transition: --c .5s;
}
.heart:hover {
    --c: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
    <button id="widget-toggle" class="widget-toggle-open drawer-toggle widget-toggle-style-default" data-toggle-target="#widget-drawer" data-toggle-body-class="showing-widget-drawer" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".widget-toggle-close">
        <span class="widget-toggle-label">MENU</span>
        <span class="widget-toggle-icon">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Specs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property

Comment: That is close, but yes, unfortunately I need support for firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mask method to create the heart shape: https://css-tip.com/image-heart-shape/

```css
.heart {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  mask:
   radial-gradient(at 70% 31%,#000 29%,#0000 30%),
   radial-gradient(at 30% 31%,#000 29%,#0000 30%),
   linear-gradient(#000 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(-41% 0,50% 91%, 141% 0);
  transition: all .5s;
}
.heart:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
    <button id="widget-toggle" class="widget-toggle-open drawer-toggle widget-toggle-style-default" data-toggle-target="#widget-drawer" data-toggle-body-class="showing-widget-drawer" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".widget-toggle-close">
        <span class="widget-toggle-label">MENU</span>
        <span class="widget-toggle-icon">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```